# Spring Boot + Aspect J configuration in Maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, aspectj

I have a Spring Boot project, which uses `@ConfigurationProcessor`, and I have a need to add `@AspectJ` post-compile weaving to a dependency.

I've added the AspectJ Maven plugin to my build, and the build then fails with an `IllegalStateException` at `org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor.processElement`. I understand that this is caused by multiple executions of an annotation processor (in this case, the Spring and AspectJ processors).

I found a mention of this issue in the [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor), which say:

> If you are using AspectJ in your project, you need to make sure that the annotation processor runs only once. There are several ways to do this. With Maven, you can configure the `maven-apt-plugin` explicitly and add the dependency to the annotation processor only there. You could also let the AspectJ plugin run all the processing and disable annotation processing in the `maven-compiler-plugin` configuration

Disabling the annotation processing in the compiler doesn't work, because I'm using Lombok, and those annotations need to be processed for compilation.

The Spring document references the `maven-apt-plugin`, which I'm not familiar with--I've only found the [`apt-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/querydsl/apt-maven-plugin) and am unsure if that's what's being referenced.

I investigated this most of yesterday, and am no closer to understanding what needs to be done to use AspectJ weaving alongside the Spring annotation processing. Is doing so possible, and if so, how?

AspectJ plugin configuration:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                    <processor>org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Attempt at configuring the `apt-maven-plugin`

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>process</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                    <processor>org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.ConfigurationMetadataAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: This setup with Spring Boot, AspectJ, Lombok, configuration processor is complex, probably you will not find many people who have done the exact same thing before. Furthermore, Lombok + AspectJ sometimes make problems when combined even without all the other stuff around. So in order to solve this, I kindly request you to produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and publish it on GitHub. Thank you.

Comment: > you will not find many people who have done the exact same thing before.
I was afraid of that. I'll work on an example over the weekend. Thanks for the feedback.